# Panoramic images in a web context: good user experience examples?

Tags: image, panning

I often create ultra-wide images on my iPhone (stitched together with Pano.app), and I'm looking for user experience examples to display them on a website. **These are not spherical or 360º images** (which many of the display tools seem to focus on).

A typical pano image aspect ratio (Gerding Theater, Portland, Oregon):

[image]

I've been using Tumblr to post photos to, because it's easy. Their ultra-wide image handling & user experience leaves much to be desired. I'd love to empower users to really get immersed in the images - either full-width or zoomed in. It wouldn't have to animate.

Have you seen:

- Any web services that handle ultra-wide images well?
- HTML only (no flash)
- Any good iOS-based UX app examples?
- Any good Wordpress photography themes that handle this use case well?
- Any other good web-based examples?

I don't mind rolling my own solution; I'm trying to think outside the box.

Got any suggestions, or examples that blew you away? Would love any links or ideas.

Comment: This question is best asked on the WebApps forum.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by showing people these panoramas?  What will seeing the panoramas help your users achieve?  I.e. can you provide any context for your users' experience?

Comment: Thanks for responding, @dnbrv. I get your point about it belonging in the WebApps forum, but I'm looking for a UX perspective more than a technical one.

Comment: I prefer the simple: show smaller version, click to load full size in its own tab/browser.

Comment: Before answering, could you detail what is the purpose of what you are looking for? What the user interaction is? Is it for the user to "post" panoramic photos, or for the user to "look at" panoramic photos?

Answer (score 1):

I dont see why a spherical engine like KR-pano wouldn't solve the problem. With the options that are given by the XML-structure, you can manipulate the intire thing and have it your way. Although KR-pano is Flash-based on a desktop-computer, it gives you plenty of options to publish on iOS-devices and Android.

You can see a view examples on my [website](http://www.littleplanet.nl/specialisme/gigapixelfotografie/49/).

On this page oy can find various panoramic photography from cylinderical projections to flat projections, all based on gigapixel-photography.

Answer (score 0):

A good overview of viewers gives you [PanoTools Wiki](http://wiki.panotools.org/Panorama_Viewers), and here is [a player comparision page](http://www.panoramaphotographer.com/comparisons/index.html).

I also love to shot panoramas, but 360°. Anyway I found [pan0.net viewer](http://pan0.net) to best suited my needs, which is [my Tumblr](http://lightinsphere.tumblr.com/tagged/panorama/page/2). But Pan0 is flash based!

Comment: Thx @FrankL. I suspect there are few, or at least not many that are common, good examples out there. Perhaps it's too unique of a use case (ultra-wide imagery).